# x264 encoder with JNA

Tags: java, video, native, jna, x264

I have been busy creating a JNA wrapper around x264.dll. I have the following class for my x264_param_t:

http://pastebin.com/Mh4JkVpP

However, when I try to initialize my x264_param_t like that

```
x264_param_t param_t = new x264_param_t;
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't determine size of nested structure: Can't instantiate class anotherReversed.x264_param_t$Vui (java.lang.InstantiationException: anotherReversed.x264_param_t$Vui)
        at com.sun.jna.Structure.calculateSize(Structure.java:790)
        at com.sun.jna.Structure.allocateMemory(Structure.java:287)
        at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:177)
        at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:167)
        at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:163)
        at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:154)
        at anotherReversed.x264_param_t.<init>(x264_param_t.java:7)
```

If I comment out the Vui in it's parent class constructor, the instantiation is ok. I wonder what is different with EXACTLY this nested structure, as there are 2 others (namely Rc and Analyse ) that are nested in the same way. Somehow, though, JNA isn't able to find the required size for Vui. Any pointers?

**Edit:
It seems that all the other nested structs (analyse and rc ) were also not initialized. I wonder why?**

Comment: Why you don't consider JNI? You may review my guide [here](http://livertmpjavapublisher.blogspot.com/2014/05/jni-for-x264-encoder.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of commenting out Vui, replace it with a Pointer and check if the other two structures are filled.

These structures are defined as inner structures within the x264_param_t struct, maybe JNA has problems with it. Take a closer look at the output of x264_param_t.toString(), as it prints calculated memory offsets.

I hope you'll find better answers at the jna [mailing list](https://jna.dev.java.net/servlets/ProjectMailingListList)

**EDIT** A dirty hack to solve the problem: use an array of ints or just dump all variables from the inner struct instead of using a separate class.

Comment: The jna mailing list, of course was my almost immediate choice to seek help. However, it seems it is back to swallowing emails. More on my question, it seemed that jna had well known (by Timothy) behavior of not automatically allocating memory to nested ByValue Structures. I am unsure if he fixed the issue as he mentioed once if enough developers request a fix he would implement it. In latest jna changelog such a fix was not mentioned but then again I might be wrong

Comment: @baba: the jna project is moving to java.net, so you might have to wait and use the new portal to seek for help. You can also try to use ffmpeg jna bridge http://code.google.com/p/ffmpeg4java/

Comment: hmm, ffmpeg4java seems to be far from being finished. I tried writing my binding a while ago, it almost worked :)

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers. I am quite familiar with the ffmepg4java project and have also tried writing my bindings for it for like 1 day...but then got second thoughts. The reasons for my second thoughts were: ffmpeg4java is scarcely developed any more, it has dependencies with JAI and JMF (which is a ghost town as well). So I decided to start afresh with the x264 as it was open source, is used by like a lot of projects (see Xuggle, Avidemux etc) and is actively developed.

Comment: @baba: what if you "inline" the struct? Just write all the variables, or use an array of ints as if there was no inner structure?

Comment: Then it works, but it complicates things in a matter of maintainability. My question, however, is answered by your comment, so you can post it as an answer so I can accept it.